# Displaying text in gridview dynamically using 2D array for android

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

I currently have a gridview inside of a scroll view that where I would like to display information
from a 2D array inside the grid view and have it scrollable. I created an adapter for the gridView to handle this job as I would like to use it for other layout later. The problem I am encountering is that only the 1st row of the array and a portion of the second is being displayed in the grid view. 
Here is my code for the adapter I created and I feel the problem lies somewhere within it:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    String[][] gridContent;
    int rowPosition, columnPosition, count;


    /**
     * 
     */
    public GridViewAdapter(Context c, String[][] content) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        context = c;
        count = 0;
        gridContent = new String[content.length][content[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < gridContent.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < gridContent[i].length; j++)
            {
                gridContent[i][j] = content[i][j];
                count++;
            }
        }
        rowPosition = 0;
        columnPosition = 0;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public int getRowCount()
    {
        return gridContent.length;
    }

    public int getColumnCount()
    {
        return gridContent[0].length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int rowNum, int columnNum)
    {
        return gridContent[rowNum][columnNum];
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup group)
    {
        TextView textView;
        if (view == null)
        {
            textView = new TextView(context);
            //textView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }
        else
        {
            textView = (TextView) view;
        }
        columnPosition = position % gridContent[0].length;
        rowPosition = (position - columnPosition)/gridContent[0].length;
        textView.setText(gridContent[rowPosition][columnPosition]);
        //textView.setTextColor(000000);
        //textView.setTextSize(13);     

        return textView;
    }


    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
THank You

I don't understand why it works perfectly fine for the 1st row and part of the second but
then it gets cut off. Here is my xml code for the scrollview and gridview:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/verticalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/networkResults" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/scheduleGrid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:numColumns="5"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >

        </GridView>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: The part at the end of your `getView()`-method makes absolutely no sense. What are you trying to archive there?

Comment: I was trying to use the variable position to relate to a specific row and column in the 2D array. Each cell in the array can be given a value where cell (X,Y) = (X * # of Columns) + Y = position. Using this and the position number I was trying to determine the columnPosition [Modulo of the position number and number of columns] and rowPosition [Quotient of (position# - columnPosition) and number of columns]. With this took the value from the 2D array and set the text in the textview.

Comment: Ok so it looks like I found out where my problem was coming from, I still don't understand why it was occuring though. I removed the scrollview from my layout and everything worked perfectly. I wasn't aware that the gridview layout will automatically become scrollable if the information overflows the layouts width/height. I implemented the scrollview portion before the gridview layout so it took me awhile to determine where the root of the bug was. Thanks for trying to help, it was greatly appreciated.